# Prove that $11^{10^n} \equiv 6\cdot 10^{n+1} + 1 \pmod{10^{n+2}}$, for $n\geq 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've managed to prove that $11^{10^n} \equiv 1 \pmod{10^{n+1}}$, using inductive arguments and the binomial expansion, but I'm struggling to prove anything about the n+2'th digit.
I've thought about using arguments of order in the group $\mathbb{Z}_{10^{n+2}}^{\times}$, but that approach didn't seem very fruitful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be going down the right path. It can indeed be proven with induction and binomial expansion.

Note that the statement is true for $n=1$, following from binomial expansion.

Assume the statement is true for $n$.

Then, calculating shows that $$11^{10^{n+1}} \equiv (10^{n+2}k+6 \times 10^{n+1}+1)^{10} \equiv 10^{n+2}k\binom{10}{1}(6 \times 10^{n+1}+1)^9+(6 \times 10^{n+1}+1)^{10} \equiv (6 \times 10^{n+1}+1)^{10} \pmod {10^{n+3}}$$

Then, $(6 \times 10^{n+1}+1)^{10} \equiv 6 \times 10^{n+1} \binom {10}{1} +1 \equiv 6 \times 10^{n+2}+1$